# How to overlap slide out navigation over buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I overlap my slide out navigation? I have listed below a simplified version of my webpage. I believe that the position of the div `#MainMenu` must remain as `position: fixed`, as if it does not remain like this then the nav will have a floating bottom if I set the position to absolute or like so. the div `#centeralign` is already set to `position: relative`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MenuIcon").click(function() {
    $("#MainMenu").css("left", "0px");
    $("#MOVE").css("left", "300px");

    function showMenu() {
      $("#MainMenu").css("-webkit-clip-path", "polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0% 100%)");
      $("#MenuIcon").animate({
        right: '-100'
      }, 300);
    }
    setTimeout(showMenu, 100);
  });

  $("#close").click(function() {
    $("#MainMenu").css("-webkit-clip-path", "polygon(0 0,0% 0,100% 100%,0% 100%)");

    function hideMenu() {
      $("#MainMenu").css("left", "-300px");
      $("#MOVE").css("left", "0px")
      $("#MenuIcon").animate({
        right: '50'
      }, 300);
    }

    setTimeout(hideMenu, 300);

    function originalLayout() {
      $("#MainMenu").css("-webkit-clip-path", "polygon(0 0,100% 0,0% 100%,0% 100%)");
    }
    setTimeout(originalLayout, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

h1 {
  color: #e5b78e;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 100pt;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: rgba(223, 190, 106, 0.7);
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 18px 80px 20px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(223, 190, 106, 0.8), rgba(146, 111, 52, 0.8), rgba(34, 34, 34, 0), rgba(34, 34, 34, 0));
  background-position: 1% 50%;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.625rem;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(223, 190, 106, 0.3);
}

.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(223, 190, 106, 0);
  color: $white;
  background-position: 99% 50%;
}

#btn1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#btn2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 47px;
  padding-right: 47px;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
}

#centeralign {
  text-align: center;
  top: 20em;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

br {
  padding: 40px;
}


/* NAV */

#MenuIcon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50;
  right: 50;
}

#MenuIcon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#MenuLine {
  height: 4px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #e5b78e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine {
  width: 40px;
}

#MenuLine::before {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #e5b78e;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine::before {
  width: 50px;
}

#MenuLine::after {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #e5b78e;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine::after {
  width: 50px;
}

#MainMenu {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #181818;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul li {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  transition: all .3s;
}

ul li:hover .line {
  width: 180px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.LOGO {
  font-size: 4.5em;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!--<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <title>A'S COFFEE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="MenuIcon">
      <div id="MenuLine"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="MainMenu">
      <div id="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">A's Coffee</h1>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>HOME
          <div class="line"></div>
        </li>
        <li>MAKE AN ORDER
          <div class="line"></div>
        </li>
        <li>VIEW ORDERS
          <div class="line"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="close">
        <P>Click to leave</P>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="centeralign">
      <a class="button" id="btn1" href="place.html">Want to Place <br>an Order?</a><br>
      <a class="button" id="btn2" href="#">View Orders?</a>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `z-index` on `#MainMenu`

```
#MainMenu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #181818;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MenuIcon").click(function() {
    $("#MainMenu").css("left", "0px");
    $("#MOVE").css("left", "300px");

    function showMenu() {
      $("#MainMenu").css("-webkit-clip-path", "polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0% 100%)");
      $("#MenuIcon").animate({
        right: '-100'
      }, 300);
    }
    setTimeout(showMenu, 100);
  });

  $("#close").click(function() {
    $("#MainMenu").css("-webkit-clip-path", "polygon(0 0,0% 0,100% 100%,0% 100%)");

    function hideMenu() {
      $("#MainMenu").css("left", "-300px");
      $("#MOVE").css("left", "0px")
      $("#MenuIcon").animate({
        right: '50'
      }, 300);
    }

    setTimeout(hideMenu, 300);

    function originalLayout() {
      $("#MainMenu").css("-webkit-clip-path", "polygon(0 0,100% 0,0% 100%,0% 100%)");
    }
    setTimeout(originalLayout, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

#MainMenu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #181818;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}

h1 {
  color: #e5b78e;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 100pt;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: rgba(223, 190, 106, 0.7);
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 18px 80px 20px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(223, 190, 106, 0.8), rgba(146, 111, 52, 0.8), rgba(34, 34, 34, 0), rgba(34, 34, 34, 0));
  background-position: 1% 50%;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.625rem;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(223, 190, 106, 0.3);
}

.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(223, 190, 106, 0);
  color: $white;
  background-position: 99% 50%;
}

#btn1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#btn2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 47px;
  padding-right: 47px;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
}

#centeralign {
  text-align: center;
  top: 20em;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

br {
  padding: 40px;
}


/* NAV */

#MenuIcon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50;
  right: 50;
}

#MenuIcon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#MenuLine {
  height: 4px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #e5b78e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine {
  width: 40px;
}

#MenuLine::before {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #e5b78e;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine::before {
  width: 50px;
}

#MenuLine::after {
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #e5b78e;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#MenuIcon:hover #MenuLine::after {
  width: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul li {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  transition: all .3s;
}

ul li:hover .line {
  width: 180px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

#close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.LOGO {
  font-size: 4.5em;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!--<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <title>A'S COFFEE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="MenuIcon">
      <div id="MenuLine"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="MainMenu">
      <div id="logo">
        <h1 class="logo">A's Coffee</h1>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>HOME
          <div class="line"></div>
        </li>
        <li>MAKE AN ORDER
          <div class="line"></div>
        </li>
        <li>VIEW ORDERS
          <div class="line"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="close">
        <P>Click to leave</P>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="centeralign">
      <a class="button" id="btn1" href="place.html">Want to Place <br>an Order?</a><br>
      <a class="button" id="btn2" href="#">View Orders?</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with @Pedram's solution https://jsfiddle.net/wtbxtfqe/2/